# JSON parse issue for duplicate data?

Tags: javascript, json

I'm constructing a `JSON` based on certain values,

my code is as follows,

```
var txt = '{ \"' + 9837 + '\": "Cost-A", \"' + 8943 + '\": "Cost-B", \"' + 13917 + '\": "Cost-C", \"' + 13917 + '\": "Cost-D"}';

_obj = JSON.parse(txt);
```

The output I get in the console is,

```
Object {9837: "Cost-A", 8943: "Cost-B", 13917: "Cost-D"}
```

`Cost-C` has been skipped completely? or is there something trivial I'm missing? How can I solve this?

Comment: Why are you constructing JSON with strings in **JavaScript**?

Comment: 13917 is duplicate key in your stringified JSON. So it is taking only latest one.

Comment: @elclanrs Well, there's a lot of mapping that's happening as well, which is beyond the scope of this question, is there an alternative way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Javascript ojects cannot have duplicate keys. Hence it gets overwritten.

{ "9837": "Cost-A", "8943": "Cost-B", **"13917"**: "Cost-C", "**13917"**: "Cost-D"}

The parser would add the latest value of the key.

Comment: You cannot use double quotes inside double quotes, until you escape them.

Comment: @badZoke , No, that would be a badJoke on the way a javascript object works. What would you expect your object to return if you do `myObj['13917']`